# Can the colon introduce only two objects?

Tags: colons

**"Here are two choices: pizza and hot dogs."**

Would that be correct, or can the colon only introduce three or more objects?

Comment: The colon can even introduce just one object.

Comment: You are asking: *can the colon introduce only two objects?*, or *can the colon only introduce three or more objects?* and your introducing sentence is  **"Here are two choices:**! You may make only one choice or two, three or as many as you like and let the colon introduce them all.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, colons can be used with any number of items, including just one:

> Rule 1a. Use a colon to introduce an item or a series of items.
>   <sub>[GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp)</sub>

Here's an example with 2:

> It's correct to say, "Grammar Girl has two favorite hobbies: watching clouds and seeing how long she can stand on one foot."
>   <sub>[Grammar Girl : Colons :: Quick and Dirty Tips ™](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/colons)</sub>

So, as long as you follow the other rules for when to use a colon (which you seem to be), any number of items can follow.